# How can I selectively apply CSS when an element doesn't have an ancestor with a certain class

Tags: css, sass, ancestor

Trying to not overwrite some existing CSS in the codebase.

```
.my-new-class {
   .existing-class {
      ...some new styles
   }
}

.existing-class {
    ...some old styles
}
```

I've tried this, which I know doesn't work and I know why:

```
.existing-class {
 :not(.my-new-class) & {
    ...some old styles
 }
}
```

but I'm failing to figure out what (or if) there's a way of accomplishing what I want.

Basically, I only want styles to apply if a certain element doesn't have an ancestor (anywhere in the tree) with a certain class....or maybe there's a better way somebody can suggest?

Thanks SO!

Comment: basically you cannot achieve this with one selector .. you can easily select the element that have an ancestor with a class but not selecting element that doesn't have an ancestor is not trivial because there is at least one ancestor (the `html` for example) so you will selecto everything

Comment: @TemaniAfif - there's the answer to my (or if)....any advice on how to try and get desired result might with a different approach?

Comment: are you able to share use case, depending on the style and the selector we may find a way to play with specificity and avoid the override

Comment: I think I found one - I turned it into a known descendent. I know my new class will always be the second ancestor. So I changed it to `.existing-class { :not(.my-new-class)>*>& { ...some old styles } }`

Comment: yes if you know the level of the ancestor then it should be easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Temani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for telling me I needed a new approach. I'm going to answer my question for anybody else who might come across it.

I changed my HTML code so that I knew the position of `.my-new-class` in the ancestor tree (made it the second ancestor) so I was able to do this:

```
.my-new-class {
   .existing-class {
      ...some new styles
   }
}

.existing-class {
   &:not(.my-new-class)>*>& {
    ...some old styles
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="existing-class">
   ...with the old style
</div>

<div class="my-new-class">
  <some-element>
    <div class="existing-class">
      ...with the new style
    </div>
  </some-element>
</div>
```